# Securely save information to off-site database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, security, single-sign-on

I promise I've done many hours of googling on this, and maybe I'm just not using the proper keywords. So I apologize if I missed something obvious here.

So what I'm trying to do is this. I'm working on a project where we'd like to keep an SSO between our vBulletin forums and a proprietary website we're working on. The trump card is that the website we're working on is an MCV C#.NET app, and will be on windows servers (likely on Azure) with the vBulletin forums on a Linux based host.

The sites will be on the same domain (via sub domains), so they will be able to share cookies. vBulletin keeps the userid, sessionhash, etc in cookies to persist the login, my MVC site would be able to access those cookies with no problem. The catch is I need to authenticate against a database that is not connected to the MVC site.

My current idea is on a successful login on the vBulletin forums to save the sessionHash along with the userid to the MVC sites SQL databases so it can authenticate against its own database. The problem is getting the sessionhash from one server to the other in the most secure way possible. I could obviously just create a controller on the MVC site to accept those two points and save them, however if someone learned said controller existed they could spoof any userid / session combo technically to gain access to the MVC site.

Basically, how do I properly get the session information from server A (Linux host) to server B (Azure host). I have access, and am familiar with PHP and the vBulletin login functions to modify them to do whatever I need, and obviously the same goes for the MVC site. Just not sure how to properly pull this off. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and please let me know if I need to elaborate further. Thanks!

Comment: Just to get an understanding, you want to authenticate against vBulletin users? That site will be the system of record for the users?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: And you have access to the vBulletin APIs?

Comment: I have the source even. I can easily retrieve the session and userid when the session is created on the login script for vB, just don't know how best to get that information over to the MVC side, or authenticate against

Comment: First, I want to disclaim that I'm not an expert on vBulletin, but I've integrated many other systems and it all kind of follows the same pattern. If you have session/user identifying information from the cookie for vBulletin, in your site, I would validate the session is valid for that user in some way. This will require the user to visit your site, your site checks cookies, and performs the check server-side in your site against vBulletin with that information.

Comment: If it's valid, at that point, you can add a record in your site with the user id to track user-specific things on your site.  But your site would never do any logins that manage users.  If it needs to do a login, I'd use whatever login api's are available on vBulletin and pass-through the credentials.

Comment: If vBulletin implements (or someone has implemented) oAuth, that might be a good place to look into implementing a single-sign-on for your site and vBulletin.